# ASP.NET Core 3.1 errors time out after Start processing HTTP request POST

Tags: timeout, httpclientfactory

I have a time out exception just after the "Start processing HTTP request POST" of HttpClientFactory
when does this message occurs exactly , is it before or after calling the server?

```
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyClient.LogicalHandler[100]
  Start processing HTTP request GET https://api.github.com/repos/aspnet/docs/branches
ritical : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Connection timed out
```